# Neural network detects only one number

Tags: python, oop, neural-network, gradient-descent

I wanted to create a neural network by myself from scratch. It is a network from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk&t=692s&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown

I use MNIST dataset from Keras.

The gradient descent works, back propjgation works, but still - network detects all numbers as one random number. I can train on all examples - using stochastic descent, I can do it on the whole dataset - as a result it detects all numbers as 2 for example, or all as 1, no matter what is in the input. I can't understand what I did wrong...

colab link

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SnNUDA2s7cGZZIXYBPFDwwNz5pLD2-Uo?usp=sharing

```
class Simple_Neural2():
  def __init__(self):
    self.input_layer_activations = np.zeros((784))
    self.weights = np.random.random(size=(16, 784))*2-1
    self.bias = np.random.random(size=(16,))*2-1

    self.first_layer_activations = sigmoid(self.weights.dot(self.input_layer_activations) + self.bias)
    self.weights1 =  np.random.random(size=(16, 16))*2-1
    self.bias1 = np.random.random(size=(16,))*2-1  

    self.second_layer_activations =  sigmoid(self.weights1.dot(self.first_layer_activations) + self.bias1)
    self.weights2 =  np.random.random(size=(10, 16))*2-1
    self.bias2 = np.random.random(size=(10,))*2-1

    self.output_layer_activations = sigmoid(self.weights2.dot(self.second_layer_activations) + self.bias2)

  def sec_l(self, ans):
    desired_vec = np.zeros(self.output_layer_activations.size)
    desired_vec[ans] = 1

    grad_w2 = np.zeros(self.weights2.shape)
    for i in range(self.output_layer_activations.size):
      z = self.weights2[i].dot(self.second_layer_activations)+self.bias2[i]
      der = self.second_layer_activations * s_der(z) * 2*(self.output_layer_activations[i]-desired_vec[i])
      grad_w2[i] = der

    grad_b2 = np.zeros(self.bias2.shape)
    z = self.weights2.dot(self.second_layer_activations) + self.bias2
    grad_b2 = s_der(z) * 2*(self.output_layer_activations-desired_vec)

    grad_a2 = np.zeros(self.second_layer_activations.shape)

    for i in range(self.second_layer_activations.size):
      z = self.weights2[:, i].dot(self.second_layer_activations[i]) + self.bias2    
      der = self.weights2[:, 0] * s_der(z) * 2*(self.output_layer_activations-desired_vec)

      grad_a2[i] = der.sum()
    


    return (grad_w2, grad_b2, self.second_layer_activations - grad_a2)


  def first_l(self, desired_vec):
    grad_w1 = np.zeros(self.weights1.shape)
    for i in range(self.second_layer_activations.size):
      z = self.weights1[i].dot(self.first_layer_activations)+self.bias1[i]
      der = self.first_layer_activations * s_der(z) * 2*(self.second_layer_activations[i]-desired_vec[i])
      grad_w1[i] = der

    grad_b1 = np.zeros(self.bias1.shape)
    z = self.weights1.dot(self.first_layer_activations) + self.bias1
    grad_b1 = s_der(z) * 2*(self.second_layer_activations-desired_vec)

    grad_a1 = np.zeros(self.first_layer_activations.shape)
    for i in range(self.first_layer_activations.size):
      z = self.weights1[:, i].dot(self.first_layer_activations[i]) + self.bias1
      der = self.weights1[:, i] * s_der(z) * 2*(self.second_layer_activations-desired_vec)
      grad_a1[i] = der.sum()


    return (grad_w1, grad_b1, self.first_layer_activations - grad_a1)



  def inp_l(self, desired_vec):  
    grad_w = np.zeros(self.weights.shape)
    for i in range(self.first_layer_activations.size):
      z = self.weights[i].dot(self.input_layer_activations)+self.bias[i]
      der = self.input_layer_activations * s_der(z) * 2*(self.first_layer_activations[i]-desired_vec[i])
      grad_w[i] = der

    grad_b = np.zeros(self.bias.shape)
    z = self.weights.dot(self.input_layer_activations) + self.bias
    grad_b = s_der(z) * 2*(self.first_layer_activations-desired_vec)
    
    return (grad_w, grad_b)


  def correct_all_1_time(self, X, y): # stohastic
    self.input_layer_activations = sigmoid(X.flatten())

    rez2 = self.sec_l(y)
    self.weights2 -= rez2[0]
    self.bias2 -= rez2[1]
    des_sec_vec = rez2[2]

    rez1 = self.first_l(des_sec_vec)
    self.weights1 -= rez1[0]
    self.bias1 -= rez1[1]
    des_f_vec = rez1[2]

    rez = self.inp_l(des_f_vec)
    self.weights -= rez[0]
    self.bias -= rez[1]


  def correct_on_all_data(self, X, y):
    grad_w2 = np.zeros(self.weights2.shape)
    grad_b2 = np.zeros(self.bias2.shape)
    grad_w1 = np.zeros(self.weights1.shape)
    grad_b1 = np.zeros(self.bias1.shape)
    grad_w = np.zeros(self.weights.shape)
    grad_b = np.zeros(self.bias.shape)
    for i in range(y.size):
      self.input_layer_activations = sigmoid(X[i].flatten())
      rez2 = self.sec_l(y[i])
      grad_w2 += rez2[0]
      grad_b2 += rez2[1]
      des_sec_vec = rez2[2]
      rez1 = self.first_l(des_sec_vec)
      grad_w1 += rez1[0]
      grad_b1 += rez1[1]
      des_f_vec = rez1[2]
      rez = self.inp_l(des_f_vec)
      grad_w += rez[0]
      grad_b += rez[1]

    self.weights2 -= (grad_w2 / len(y))
    self.bias2 -= (grad_b2 / len(y))
    self.weights1 -= (grad_w1 / len(y))
    self.bias1 -= (grad_b1 / len(y))
    self.weights-= (grad_w / len(y))
    self.bias -= (grad_b / len(y))



  def get_prediction(self, input_layer):
    self.input_layer_activations = sigmoid(input_layer.flatten())
    self.first_layer_activations = sigmoid(self.weights.dot(self.input_layer_activations) + self.bias)
    self.second_layer_activations =  sigmoid(self.weights1.dot(self.first_layer_activations) + self.bias1)
    self.output_layer_activations = sigmoid(self.weights2.dot(self.second_layer_activations) + self.bias2)
    return self.output_layer_activations

  def predict(self, input_layer):
    return np.argmax(self.get_prediction(input_layer))
```

UPD. Example of usage

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(X, y), (testX, testy) = mnist.load_data()

network = Simple_Neural2()
# batch gradient descent
for _ in range(100):
  network.correct_on_all_data(X, y)
network.predict(X[0]) # 2
network.predict(X[1]) # 2
...
network.predict(X[9000]) # 2
```

tried stohastic descent

```
network = Simple_Neural2()
for i in range(10000):
  network.correct_all_1_time(X[i], y[i])
```

same rezult.

upd2. used functions

```
def reLU(x):
  return np.maximum(x, np.zeros(x.shape[0]))

def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def s_der(x):
  return np.exp(x)/np.square(1+np.exp(x))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with your code where you actually use the above defined class. This makes it easier.

Comment: @FredMaster
u r right, done.